# CLOCK_MONOTONIC not found

Tags: eclipse, g++

I am attempting to use clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ts ).  I have included time.h, and linked to librt (I think).  I still get the error that CLOCK_MONOTONIC is undefined.  (EDIT:  error text added)

```
Symbol 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' could not be resolved  ...   Semantic Error
```

c++ in eclipse.  In myrojname->properties->C/C++ Build->GCC C++ Linker->libraries I added "rt".  The resulting command line includes -lrt.

I tried a much simpler scratch program and compiled from the command line with **g++ -o mytest mytest.cpp -lrt** and it works great.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: You should post the exact error message.

Comment: Symbol 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' could not be resolved ... Semantic Error

Comment: Have you added the library it to your active build target? Are there any other libraries present?

Comment: Yes (Debug) and NO - no other libraries are required....yet.   Any suggestion on how I might tell if it actually is being linked?

Comment: After much though, I finally realized I did not have the link nad include paths set up correctly in Eclipse.  A thousand years from now I may learn to use the now current version of that tool :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's actually an error message coming out of the CDT static analyser, *not* something from the compiler itself.

And I think it's complaining about the code itself rather than something missing from the linkage objects, so whether you link with `rt` or not is not relevant (for this particular issue anyway).

You should go into the C++ settings, specifically the include paths, and ensure that all needed directories are listed there.